# Error during saving of record with rid

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

odb version: 2.2.17

This error is produced randomly while trying to update a linkmap entry in a record. Once the error appears, it persists even after a db restart.

> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Error
>   during saving of record with rid #10:139

I have a large time series database (over 300 GB of data) which I have been writing to and reading from for the past two years. The database worked through various versions of OrientDb.

A few days ago I noticed the above error when the program was trying to write to the db. I have not changed anything in the code for over a year so I thought this was very strange.

I assumed that the database got corrupted somehow and wanted to give it a fresh start. I went ahead and deleted the record that was failing. I also deleted its parent and children (db is a tree structure). I started writing to the database again and the problem appeared to have gone away.. until, it came up again a couple hours later. I tried deleting the problematic records again. The program was able to write to the db for some time, but then the problem appeared again. The timing seems to be random.

I updated to 2.2.17 (from 2.2.12) but it made no difference.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: This doesnt look good... Have you submitted issue to github? Which driver are you using?

Comment: I am connecting with plocal in a java program. I have also submitted to google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/7ST1oqydy9g and i need to reply back with a full stack trace. it looks like it is a bug

Comment: Plz, do. These guys usually fix severe bugs in the next bugfix release